# ArcGIS API for Javascript: FeatureLayerCollection doesn't displaye all the features

Tags: javascript, arcgis

[This image shows the result of my implementation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U84io.png)

The problem here is the feaure layer displayed in the map shows only one of the features passed in the code.

*How have I done it?*

1. Create a feature layer using `new FeatureLayer(featureCollectionObject, options?)`.
2. Create a Query and QueryTask to request features from the arcgi server.

   ```
   var selectQuery: Query = new Query();
   selectQuery.returnGeometry = true;
   selectQuery.where = "1=1";
   selectQuery.outFields = ["NAME", "X", "Y"];
   var queryTask_XZQH = new QueryTask(FL_XZQH_URL);
   queryTask_XZQH.execute(selectQuery);
   ```
3. Define a event handler for "complete" of queryTask.

   ```
   function onQueryTask_XZQHComplete(evt: object) {
   console.log(evt.featureSet.geometryType);
       //console.log(evt.featureSet);
       FL_XZQH = new FeatureLayer({
           featureSet: evt.featureSet,
           layerDefinition: {
               geometryType: "esriGeometryPolygon",
               className: "xzqh",
               objectIdField:"OBJECTID",
               fields: [
                   {
                       name: "OBJECTID ",
                       type:"esriFieldTypeOID",
                       alias:"OBJECTID"
                   },
                   {
                       name: "ID ",
                       type:"esriFieldTypeInteger ",
                       alias:"Id"
                   },
                   {
                       name: "Name",
                       type: "esriFieldTypeString",
                       length: 50,
                       alias: "行政区划名称"
                   },
                   {
                       name: "X",
                       type: "esriFieldTypeDouble",
                       alias: "经度"
                   },
                   {
                       name: "Y",
                       type: "esriFieldTypeDouble",
                       alias: "纬度"
                   }
               ]

           }
       });
       map.addLayer(FL_XZQH);
   }
   ```

The result of  QueryTask is fine, and the count of the features is 18.

However, when I use `map.addLayer`, the map just displays one feature.

Comment: This must be the ArcGIS API for JavaScript 3.x, not 4.x, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature layer does not have a valid object ID. Make two changes to fix it:

1. Change this:

   `selectQuery.outFields = ["NAME", "X", "Y"];`

   To this (i.e. include the object ID in your query):

   `selectQuery.outFields = ["OBJECTID", "NAME", "X", "Y"];`
2. Change this:

   `{
        name: "OBJECTID ",
        type:"esriFieldTypeOID",
        alias:"OBJECTID"
    },`

   To this (i.e. remove the space at the end of the field name):

   `{
        name: "OBJECTID",
        type:"esriFieldTypeOID",
        alias:"OBJECTID"
    },`

Note: this will only work if the feature service actually has a field called `OBJECTID`.